# How to fetch nested repeated BQ table in python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have a table with nested and repeated columns. I want the data fetched in python and having same format as BQ to transform the data as needed.

Is there a package to do the same?

Comment: You can `UNNEST()` your BigQuery data when you query it and return this as a dataframe - is this what you mean?

Comment: No. Without using unnest or flatten. How to fetch nested and repeated fields in python dataframe?

Comment: You can't fetch a nested value from an array without first unnesting it. Are you able to share some example code to better demonstrate your issue?